# If Else Statement JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble getting my if then statement to work.

I have `city` defined as a variable and it is being logged onto the console correctly.

**Javascript**

```
function getPic() {
  if (city === "Austin") {
    $("body").addClass("austin");
  } else {
    if (city === "New York") {
      $("body").addClass("nyc");
    } else {
      if (city === "Sydney") {
        $("body").addClass("sydney");
      } else {
        if (city === "Los Angeles") {
          $("body").addClass("la");
        } else {
          if (city === "San Francisco") {
            $("body").addClass("sf");
          }
        }
```

Comment: Logging correctly? What is the problem then?

Comment: Why not use `switch` statement here?

Comment: `else if` - not just `else`

Comment: Also, you braces don't match up

Comment: I edited the code to format it correct, which makes the mistake pretty obvious to see.

Comment: I'm going to assume you are trying to get the body to show the TEXT "austin", "nyc", "syndney"...

You shouldn't use addClass but use html, such as $("body").html("austin").

Comment: `else` semantically means "in all other cases".  Logically, how can you possibly have multiple `else` clauses?  "in all *other* other cases"?

Answer (score 2):

```
function getPic(){
    if (city=== "Austin") {
        $("body").addClass("austin");
    } else if (city=== "New York") {
        $("body").addClass("nyc");
    } else if (city=== "Sydney") {
        $("body").addClass("sydney");
    } else if (city=== "Los Angeles") {
        $("body").addClass("la");
    } else if (city==="San Francisco") {
        $("body").addClass("sf");
    }
}
```

Comment: you're too slow young padawan~

Comment: sorry @Blag , for being first in the row :)

Comment: @Blag please keep your comments professional. This isn't a contest and there is no reason to be insulting

Comment: @charlietfl insulting ? XD no, no at all, Just we came with the same answer in 10s, that's funny. Btw, the Op add some data on my post, so I think I now fix it.

Comment: @charlietfl but the one that downvote 2 of my question just now by revenge is really insulting. why a comment here should change the value of my other questions ?

Comment: @charlietfl , I did not take that in that sense.. It's not a serious issue. but downvote is bad thing in such a case.. I don't know who did this but it's not good ..

Answer (score 1):

this is  what you want :

```
function getPic(city) {
  if (city === "Austin") {
    $("body").addClass("austin");
  } else if (city === "New York") {
    $("body").addClass("nyc");
  } else if (city === "Sydney") {
    $("body").addClass("sydney");
  } else if (city === "Los Angeles") {
    $("body").addClass("la");
  } else if (city === "San Francisco") {
    $("body").addClass("sf");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#entry").submit(stoppingDefaultBehavior);
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var city = $("#city-type").val();
    console.log(city);
    getPic(city);
  });
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 
 // $("#entry").submit(stoppingDefaultBehavior);
 $("form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var city= $("#city-type").val();
  console.log (city);
  getPic();
 });


});


function getPic() {
  if (city === "Austin") {
    $("body").addClass("austin");
  } else if (city === "New York") {
    $("body").addClass("nyc");
  } else if (city === "Sydney") {
    $("body").addClass("sydney");
  } else if (city === "Los Angeles") {
    $("body").addClass("la");
  } else if (city === "San Francisco") {
    $("body").addClass("sf");
  }
}

Comment: @RahulMenon update, take a look